# Concat and merge operations moving data into single partition for pyspark.pandas api

Tags: pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

In spark latest release (3.2.0), they have provided availability to use pandas on pyspark, with just

```
import pyspark.pandas as ps
```

But when I'm trying to use join and merge operation on these pandas dataframe, these get combined into a single partition , is there any way to avoid this ?

Error - which I'm getting

```
WARN WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation
```

Comment: what's the code that is being executed? the error is not an error but a warning, so your code would still work, just not optimally.

Comment: This is a warning. The windowing function does not specify the ```partition by``` clause, and all data is placed in one partition. Check the window function code.

Comment: Don't you think, when I go for large files for processing it'll cause an issue as data won't be distributed among different partitions?
As there would be single partition and rest partitions would be empty